# Extending from FormField in a Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter

Extending from FormField in a Stateful Widget

I have a Stateful widget with properties and functions. I would like to extend the widget from FormField, because I need to validate some user input on the widget.

It seems that it is not possible to extend from multiple classes (StatefulWidget and FormField).

If I try to create a normal class that extends from FormField:

```
class CustomInput extends FormField<bool> {
  final Widget label;
  final void Function(bool?) onChanged;

  userClicked() {
    print('User clicked');
  }

  CustomInput({
    required this.label,
    required this.onChanged,
    FormFieldValidator<bool>? validator,
  }) : super(
          validator: validator,
          builder: (field) {           
            return Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => userClicked(), //<-- The instance member 'userClicked' can't be accessed in an initializer.
                  child: Text('Call internal function'),
                ),
```

... then I cannot access internal methods because of the 'The instance member 'userClicked' can't be accessed in an initializer.' error.

So how do you create a widget that extends from FormField to use the `validator`, `onChanged`, `onSaved` etc., but at the same time have internal logic that can be accessed normally from the widget tree?

Comment: one thing, you can put your `userClicked` actions on `onPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending FormField, the solution was to return a FormField from the StatefulWidget. In this example the validation content is a string array, but it can of course be whatever:

```
class CustomInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? Function(List<String>)? validator;
  final Function(List<String>)? onChanged;

  const CustomInput({this.onChanged, this.validator, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomInput> createState() => _CustomInputState();
}

class _CustomInputState extends State<CustomInput> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  
 userClicked() {
    print('User clicked');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField(validator: ((value) {
      if (widget.validator != null) {
        return widget.validator!(widget.imagePaths);
      }
      return null;
    }), builder: (FormFieldState<List<String>> state) {
      return Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => userClicked(), //<-- The instance member 'userClicked' can't be accessed in an initializer.
                  child: Text('Call internal function'),
                ),
                ]
          );
        
    });
  }
}
```